# Calculating equal tokens

Tags: javascript, php

I want to verify a user by a token. One token is calculated client-side (JavaScript), the other is calculated server-side (PHP). If they're equal the user gets access.

I'm using some random variables, the current time and the user ID in this calculation. What are good ways to validate it's the user? I don't want to do it by a password.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using "random" variables and hoping they collide, why not use a HMAC of a secret? I'll give a similar example:

For preventing CSRF attacks on forms in the websites I build, I randomly generate a 20-byte string and store it in $_SESSION['formTokens']. When the form is displayed to the user, I add `<input type="hidden" name="csrf" value="<?=hash_hmac('sha1', $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'], $_SESSION['formTokens']['thisFormID']);" />` to the form.

When the form is submitted, I check (using a constant time hash comparison function) that `$_POST['csrf']` and `hash_hmac('sha1', $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'], $_SESSION['formTokens']['thisFormID'])` have the same value.

You could do something similar here.

Comment: Thanks! Pretty clever way of working ;-)